# Very simple Javascript ad placement engine

Tags: javascript, image

I have ten different banner ads uploaded on my site. I want to make a Javascript program that will randomly show one each time a page is loaded. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you save the urls to an array and then pick an index with a random function between 0-9 and your done

function:

```
var rand_no = Math.ceil(10*Math.random())
```

array

```
var image=new Array(); 
image[0]="image.jpg";       
image[1]="image.jpg";
image[2]="image.jpg";
```

etc

```
alert(image[rand_no]);
```

Comment: Easier to use an array literal, ie. `var image = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];` perhaps :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it server-side? i.e. before rendering the page, you pick one banner from your server?

If you really must do it using javascript, consider using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Google is overwhelming with ad rotators. Checkout:

- [The JavaScript Source: Text Effects: Banner Ad Rotator](http://javascript.internet.com/text-effects/banner-ad-rotator.html)
- [A JavaScript Banner Ad Rotator Script](http://www.brettb.com/js_banner_ad_rotator.asp)